# When I analyze the speed from my separator algorithms, why do I get these outliers at specific points?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, time, statistics

I'm learning about algorithms, complexity, and data science. I wrote two functions that break apart a list of 1000 numbers into a list of each number in it's own list.

For example,

`[1,2,3,4,5]` would become `[[1], [2], [3], [4], [5]]`

It isn't practical, but the point is to see how the functions scale. *'divsep'* separates the list by using **recursion** and *'ifsep'* separates the list using **iteration.** The script I wrote generates lists of length 1 to 1000 and tests the amount of time it takes to sort those list sizes with each different function.

However, I'm getting consistent outliers at specific points in the data, particularly at list sizes of 400 and 800 and I'm not sure why. The code is below.

```
import time

def divsep(prime_list,fresh_list = []):
    '''takes an input list of size x and breaks it down into x lists of size 1 
    using recursion'''
    if len(prime_list) == 0:
        return fresh_list
    else:
        new = prime_list.pop()
        list_entry = [new]
        fresh_list.append(list_entry)
        return divsep(prime_list, fresh_list)


def ifsep(list_input):
    '''takes an input list of size x and breaks it down into x lists of size 1 
    using iteration'''
    new_list = []
    for item in list_input:
        ind = [item]
        new_list.append(ind)
    return new_list


with open('divsep.csv', 'w') as f:
    f.write('"Algorithm","Range","Time"\n')
    for number in range(1,1000):
        list1 = [x for x in range(1,number)]
        sum1 = 0
        for numnum in range(100):
            t1 = time.perf_counter()
            divsep(list1)
            t2 = time.perf_counter()
            sum1 += t2-t1
        f.write(f'"divsep","{number}","{sum1/100}"\n')


with open('ifsep.csv', 'w') as f:
    f.write('"Algorithm","Range","Time"\n')
    for number in range(1,1000):
        list1 = [x for x in range(1,number)]
        sum1 = 0
        for number in range(100):
            t3 = time.perf_counter()
            ifsep(list1)
            t4 = time.perf_counter()
            sum1 += t4-t3

        f.write(f'"ifsep","{number}","{sum1/100}"\n')


print('End program')
```

I use this code in Jupyter Notebook to display the results on line graphs.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

recursion_separators = pd.io.parsers.read_csv('divsep.csv')
iteration_separators = pd.io.parsers.read_csv('ifsep.csv')


recursive_values = list(recursion_separators[['Time'][0]])
plt.plot(range(1,1000), recursive_values, 'm')
plt.show()

iteration_values = list(iteration_separators[['Time'][0]])
plt.plot(range(1,1000), iteration_values, 'b')
plt.show()
```

[image: 'Results for Separation with recursion']

[image: Results for Separation with iteration]

For both graphs, the x axis is the list size and the y axis is the time it takes to run the algorithm. The purple (top graph) are the results for the recursion separator, while the blue (bottom graph) displays the results for the iterative separator.

My assumption is that these values should scale consistently, so when I initially saw these outliers, I thought that maybe it extra time added because my computer is running other software, making the testing slower than it should be. To fix that, I added to the program and made it to where it runs each list of n size 100 times and then gets an average. I figured this would offset any outliers, but I does not. Besides, the ticks always appear in the same tick marks, particularly 400 and 800 for the top graph.

I'm not sure if it's a problem with my code, computer, or understanding of stats, so I hope that someone will be able to shed some light on the topic.

Thanks!

My versions are:
python: 3.7,
spyder: 3.3.6,
jupyter core: 4.5.0,
jupyter-notebook: 6.0.1,

Comment: I suspect that this is related to memory management. Python will automatically resize lists to fit all the data as its added. This produces behavior that is smooth on average, but peaky on occasion when resizing happens. Your timing artifacts are all near numbers with lots of factors of 2, which also hints at memory management as a root cause.

Comment: @mcskinner That's what I was afraid of. I was originally using the timeit module instead of time because I had heard that time could have these type of issues. However, I had issues with timeit so switch to time. Maybe that is indeed the cause. I'll try to rewrite it with timeit. Thanks!

Comment: @mcskinner If your hypothesis is correct, wouldn't you expect to see steps in the runtime not spikes? Why would partitioning a list of length 400 be much slower than either 399 or 401 items?

Comment: Not necessarily. Garbage collection and memory management has a lot of quirks, and one of them is that object recycling (1) helps a lot when it works but (2) doesn't always line up how you want. Some specific list sizes are going to be harder to work with.